# How do I tell Bundler to treat a git repository as a rubygem source?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I am having a project that depends on private gems and on those from rubygems.org.
It is well-known that one can explicitely load a gem from a git repository via:

```
gem 'mygem', :git => git@git.myserver.com:myuser/mygem.git'
```

However, this behaviour is not desirable as I would have to add such a line for each dependency I am specifying in my gemspec. Furthermore, this way Bundler will only check out the gemspec on the latest commit in the master branch and thus fails if it doesn't meet the needs rather than searching the repository for a (tagged) commit which matches the version requirements of the dependency.

For instance, if I have specified `spec.add_development_dependency "mygem", "~> 1.0.12"` in my gemspec, a first attempt to specify the source for mygem inside of my Gemfile would be `gem 'mygem', :git => '...', :tag => '1.0.12'`. But what if a new commit with tag 1.0.13 gets released? I always would have to manually adjust the tag specifier in the Gemfile to the latest version which is not desirable at all. 
When using a gem server, Bundler can download the specs4.8.gz file which contains an index list of all available gems and versions - I want to mime this behaviour for git as well without the need of an additional gem package server hosting *.gem files.

Here is what I came up with for my gemspec:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
     spec.add_development_dependency "mygem", "~> 1.0.12", "<= 1.0.20"
     ...
     $hook = spec
end
```

... and my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec

# This function scans a repository for a tagged commit fulfilling the requirements of dep
# somewhat equivalent to requesting for and reading in specs4.8.gz
def query_tags dep
    vers = `git tag -l 'v*.*.*'`.split(/\n+/) # store all gem version tags in an array
    vers.each { |ver| ver[0] = '' } # remove leading 'v'
    vers.sort_by{ |ver| Gem::Version.new(ver) } # sort the list
    vers.reverse_each do |ver| # find the latest compatible version
        return ver if dep.match?(dep.name, ver)
    end
    raise "No version in repository found fulfilling the requirements of " + dep.name + "!"
end

unless $hook.nil?
    $hook.dependencies.each do |dep| 
        `mkdir tmpindex` # create a git directory for storing tags
        repo = 'git@git.myserver.com:myuser/' + dep.name + '.git'
        `git -C ./tmpindex init --quiet`
        if system("git -C ./tmpindex remote add origin #{repo}") 
            # fetch all tags in the commit 
            if system("git -C ./tmpindex fetch --all --tags --prune --quiet")
                gem dep.name, :git => repo, :tag => 'v' + query_tags(dep)
            end
        end
        `rm -rf tmpindex`
    end
end
```

This approach has some drawbacks:

- At *each* bundle operation (such as bundle exec) and not just at install or update, the remote repositories will be scanned for tags, slowing everything down.
- Github will be scanned for repositores belonging to gems that are on rubygems, not on the private repository. As these will fail anyways, it pointlessly slows everything down even more.

Is there any more elegant way to accomplish this? What can I do about the drawbacks? Are there any obvious gotchas I have not considered?

Comment: i don't understand your problem, you can tell bundler to use a specific SHA, branch or tag that should be used.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that I don't know which tag to use inside the Gemfile. For instance, if my project depends on my_gem with version ~> 1.0.4, how would I transport this version requirement to `gem "my_gem", :git => ...`? If I use :tag, I could just hard-code 1.0.4 there, but that is not what ~> 1.0.4 means. If for example my_gem with version 1.0.5 gets released, the Gemfile will not consider it until I manually modify the tag specifier. I already specified the version I need in my gemspec file, I don't want to repeat that in my Gemfile.

Comment: You have to make sure that there is a git tag like `1.0.latest` that always points to the lastest `1.0.x` tag.

Comment: Still, this won't account for all cases. Imagine the dependency reads "~> 1.0.3", "<= 1.0.9". If a version 1.0.10 is available, 1.0.latest will refer to it.